# is there a "if not<" or "if not >" command in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to see if there is a if not > or if not < command in python.  I know there is **while !=** for if not equal to so I tried !> and !< but it doesn't seem to be recognized. I am trying to run something like:

```
while variable != 18:

variable += 1
```

Except replace the != command with !> or !<.

Comment: Why would you need that? You can simply use the sign the other way around e.g. `!<` becomes `>=`

Comment: you can do if not (var > number) or if not (var < number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!>` would be `<=` and `!<` would be `>=`

To explain, if a number is not greater than `x`, then it could be equal to it or less than it. The same goes for ‘not less than’ becoming greater than or equal to.